# Syntax error: identifier not found... But i have included it? C++

Tags: c++

I have a Game class -

**Game.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Screen.h"
#include "Script.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game( HWND hWnd, const MouseServer &mouseServer, const ScreenServer &screenServer );
    void Go();
    void Config();

private:    
    void ComposeFrame();

    D3DGraphics gfx;
    MouseClient mouse;
    ScreenClient screen;

    Script * scripts[ 1 ];
};
```

I have a D3DGraphics class -

**D3DGraphics.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#include "Screen.h"
#include "Script.h"

#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z, rhw;    // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
    DWORD color;    // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
};

class D3DGraphics
{
public:
    D3DGraphics( HWND hWnd, ScreenClient screenClient );
    ~D3DGraphics();

    void Begin();
    void End();
    void Present();

    void CreateViewport();
    void DefineText( Script *script );

    LPDIRECT3D9 d3dObject;
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3dDevice;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS presParams;
    HRESULT hr;

    float ResizeLockRatio( float width, float height, float scalingWidth );
    float GetGameOffset( float resizedImageHeight );

    void DrawRectangle( int x, int y, int width, int height, D3DCOLOR backgroundColor );
    void DrawActionBar();
    void RenderText( Script *script );
private:
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 vBuffer;
    ScreenClient screen;
};
```

Notice that the Game class has both

```
D3DGraphics gfx;
Script * scripts[ 1 ];
```

In my Game.cpp I make a version of D3DGraphics and place it in gfx:

**Game.cpp**:

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game( HWND hWnd, const MouseServer &mouseServer, const ScreenServer &screenServer )
    :   mouse( mouseServer ),
        screen( screenServer ),
        gfx( hWnd, screen )
{
    //gfx.d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);

    std::string debugStringResult;
    std::stringstream debugString;
    debugString << "Mouse X: " << mouse.GetMouseX() << ",\nMouse Y: " << mouse.GetMouseY() << ",\nLeft mouse down: " << mouse.LeftMouseDown() << ",\nRight mouse down: " << mouse.RightMouseDown() << ",\nScreen width: " << screen.GetScreenWidth() << ",\nScreen height: " << screen.GetScreenHeight() << "\nSystem resolution: " << screen.GetWindowWidth() << " x " << screen.GetWindowHeight();
    debugStringResult = debugString.str();
        scripts[ 0 ] = new Script( gfx, "Arial", 0, 0, 255, 0, debugStringResult, 10, 10, ( screen.GetWindowWidth() - 10 ), ( screen.GetWindowHeight() - 10 ) );
}
```

I have a  Script class -

**Script.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include <sstream>

class Script
{
public: 
    Script( D3DGraphics gfx,
            LPCSTR font, 
            int alpha, int r, int g, int b, 
            std::string text, 
            float x, float y, float width, float height );

    LPCSTR font;
    int alpha, r, g, b;
    std::string text;
    float x, y, width, height;
    D3DCOLOR color;
    RECT rect;
    ID3DXFont *handle;
private:
};
```

My Script constructor looks like this:

**Script.cpp**:

```
#include "Script.h"

Script::Script( D3DGraphics gfx,
                LPCSTR font, 
                int alpha, int r, int g, int b, 
                std::string text, 
                float x, float y, float width, float height )
{
    gfx.DefineText( this );
}
```

And so on. Now the error when I compile my application comes up as:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DGraphics'    c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\script.h   9   1   TheGame
Error   8   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DGraphics'    c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\script.h   9   1   TheGame
Error   9   error C2661: 'Script::Script' : no overloaded function takes 11 arguments   c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\game.cpp   14  1   TheGame
Error   10  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Script' c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\d3dgraphics.h  28  1   TheGame
Error   11  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Script' c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\d3dgraphics.h  40  1   TheGame
Error   12  error C2660: 'D3DGraphics::DefineText' : function does not take 1 arguments c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\script.cpp 9   1   TheGame
Error   13  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DGraphics'    c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\script.h   9   1   TheGame
Error   16  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'D3DGraphics'    c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\script.h   9   1   TheGame
```

Line 9 of Script.h is:

```
Script( D3DGraphics gfx,...
```

I honestly have no idea what on earth is happening? Does anyone have a clue, I've been poking at the code like a dead animal for the past 2 hours.

Comment: do you know that D3D is being compiled before script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependency, so you might need to specify you want D3DGraphics compiled before script, this is done by:

```
#pragma once

#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include <sstream>

class D3DGraphics;

class Script
{
public: 
    Script( D3DGraphics gfx,
            LPCSTR font, 
            int alpha, int r, int g, int b, 
            std::string text, 
            float x, float y, float width, float height );

    LPCSTR font;
    int alpha, r, g, b;
    std::string text;
    float x, y, width, height;
    D3DCOLOR color;
    RECT rect;
    ID3DXFont *handle;
private:
};
```

Comment: Have I got my self snookered here? When I declare as above, I then get the same errors for D3DGraphics: Error 9 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Script' c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\thegame\thegame\d3dgraphics.h 28 1 TheGame

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Need4Sleep, your circular inclusion of `D3DGraphics.h` and `Script.h` is the problem. One way you can resolve this is to just forward declare your script class instead of including its header in `D3DGraphics.h`.

For example:

```
#pragma once

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

#include "Screen.h"

#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

class Script;
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    FLOAT x, y, z, rhw;    // from the D3DFVF_XYZRHW flag
    DWORD color;           // from the D3DFVF_DIFFUSE flag
};

class D3DGraphics
{
public:
    D3DGraphics( HWND hWnd, ScreenClient screenClient );
    ~D3DGraphics();

    // rest of D3DGraphics's definition
};
```

This will work as long as `D3DGraphics` doesn't have inlined methods that uses your `Script` class in a substantive manner. eg. pointers to Script is fine.